# Get blank page after submit in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am working on CI and i created one simple CRUD to insert PDF with some data in table. Sometimes my code works but now its completely not working.I am getting blank page after submitting my form. And nothing is happens like print_r and var_dump etc. I dont know whats wrong in my code.

My sidebar : 
From where i click to my controller to get my view.

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('responsible/add_pay_slips');?>">Upload Pay slips</a></li>
```

Its working fine. On click this i am able to go to my page that is add_pay_slips.

Controller for the same:

```
 public function add_pay_slips()
  { 
    $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar');
    $data['salary']=$this->pay_slips->getPaySlips1();    
    $this->load->view('responsibilities/add_pay_slips',$data);
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
  }
```

After this i get my form view:

```
          <form  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url();?>responsible/upload">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Select Month</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select name="month">
              <option value="1">January</option>
              <option value="2">February</option>
              <option value="3">March</option>
              <option value="4">April</option>
              <option value="5">May</option>
              <option value="6">June</option>
              <option value="7">July</option>
              <option value="8">August</option>
              <option value="9">September</option>
              <option value="10">October</option>
              <option value="11">November</option>
              <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Select Year</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select name="year">
              <option>2017</option>
              <option>2016</option>
              <option>2015</option>                 
              <option>2014</option>                 
              <option>2013</option>
              <option>2012</option>
              <option>2011</option>                 
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Select Employee</label>
          <div class="controls">               
            <select name="employee_name">
            <?php 
              foreach ($salary  as $row) {?>
              <option value='<?php echo $row->EMPLOYEE_ID;?>'><?php  echo $row->EMPLOYEE_NAME;}?></option>
              <!--<input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="<?php //echo $row->EMPLOYEE_ID?>">-->

            </select>            
          </div>
        </div>
               <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Select Country</label>
          <div class="controls">               
            <select name="org_id">            
              <option  value="40">UK</option>        
              <option  value="65">INDIA</option>
              <option  value="47">POLAND</option> 
              <option  value="57">GERMANY</option>  
            </select>            
          </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Upload Payslip</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="file"  name="userfile"/>
          </div>
        </div>           
        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

and for this view on submit button i created one controller to insert data.

```
    function upload(){

    $filename = 'pdf';
    $config = array(
      'upload_path' => 'uploads',
      'allowed_types' => "pdf",
      'file_name' => $filename
    );
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload())
      {
      $file_data = $this->upload->data();      
      $data1['userfile'] = $file_data['file_name'];
      $data=
      array(
      'PAY_MONTH'=>$this->input->post('month'),
      'PAY_YEAR'=>$this->input->post('year'),
      'ORG_ID'=>$this->input->post('org_id'),
      'EMPLOYEE_ID'=>$this->input->post('employee_name'),
      'PDF'=>$data1['userfile'],
      );      
      $this->load->model('pay_slips_model');
       $result=$this->pay_slips->insert_payslips($data);
      if($result==true)
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"PDF  Added Successfully");     
          $this->load->view('layouts/header');
          $this->load->view('layouts/sidebar');
          $data['salary']=$this->pay_slips->getPaySlips1();    
          $this->load->view('responsibilities/add_pay_slips' ,$data,'refresh');
          $this->load->view('layouts/footer');


        }
      else
        {



          $this->seesion->set_flashdata('msg1',"PDF Added Failed");
          redirect('responsibilities/add_pay_slips');


        }     
      }

  }
```

And for this i have one model to insert data.

```
public function insert_payslips($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert('all_salary_slip_details',$data);
            return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;
        }
```

I have one page responsible.php my all controllers are on the same page.What is affecting my code. i am stuck here. Onclick Submit i just got my controller's url and blank page.   `payroll1/responsible/upload`.

Comment: Check you have used string in place of integer in ID. may be in orgid

Comment: thanks for your help @Artier but i get solution earlier i was having issue in my code